# How to return response from async GuzzleHttp request to outer function or handle Exception in yii2?

Tags: promise, yii2, guzzle

I need to send async post request in background and save response (status code and request body to DB). I decide to use GuzzleHttp package (v6) for it.

The idea is run function `sendAsyncRequest`, send async request inside it, then get response from resource in array with keys `code`, `data`, return this array to outer function `processAsyncRequest` and then send it to function `logResponse` to save it to db.

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client as GuzzleClient;

class Logger 
{

public function processAsyncRequest($client)
{
    $response = $this->sendAsyncRequest($client->phone, ['utm_source' => $client->utm_source]);
    $this->logResponse($client, $response);
}

public function sendAsyncRequest($phone, $params)
{
    $url_params = http_build_query(['utm_source' => $client->utm_source]);

    $guzzleClient = new GuzzleClient();
    $headers = [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Authorization' => 'Basic xxxxxxxxxx',
        ];
    $request = new Request('POST', 'url' . $phone . '/tokens/?' . $url_params, $headers);

    $promise = $guzzleClient->sendAsync($request);

    $promise->then(
        function (ResponseInterface $response) {
            return [
                'code' => $response->getStatusCode(),
                'body' => $response->getBody()->__toString(),
            ];
        },
            function(RequestException $e) {
                return [
                    'code' => $e->getResponse()->getStatusCode(),
                    'body' => $e->getMessage(),
                ];
            }
        );
    $res = $promise->wait();
    return $res;
}

public function logResponse($client, $data)
{
    $log = new Log();
    $log->client_id = $client->id;
    $log->url = 'url';
    $log->response = $data['code'] . ', ' . $data['body'];
    $log->comment = 'reg';
    return $log->save();
}

}
```

The problems are:

1. function `sendAsyncRequest` returns object of `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response`, I see the error "Cannot use object of type GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response as array" and I have no idea how to get my `$res` array from it.
2. how to correctly handle exception if promise will return error?